# How to show a subtitle only in one frame in Avisynth?

Tags: avisynth

I have the following script in Avisynth. It generates two frames with two subtitles. One subtitle changes the text and the second subtitle is shown in both frames, unchanged. What I need is to show the second subtitle only in the first frame. How can I do that?

```
BlankClip(width=640, height=360, length=1, fps=1, color=$FFFFFF)
Subtitle("123", size=100, x=320, y=290, align=2, text_color=$0000ff) \
++ Subtitle("456", size=100, x=320, y=290, align=2, text_color=$0000ff)
Subtitle("ABC", size=100, x=620, y=360, align=3, text_color=$000000)
```

I am using Avisynth+ 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using splice and append

```
BlankClip(width=640, height=360, length=1, fps=1, color=$FFFFFF)
Subtitle("123", size=100, x=320, y=290, align=2, text_color=$0000ff)
Subtitle("ABC", size=100, x=620, y=360, align=3, text_color=$000000)
a=last

BlankClip(width=640, height=360, length=1, fps=1, color=$FFFFFF)
Subtitle("456", size=100, x=320, y=290, align=2, text_color=$0000ff)
b=last

a+b
```